# Can I use a WHILE loop inside a SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, while-loop, union

I need to create a formatted text (CSV) output with an even number of columns from a SQL query of two tables that do not have the same number of elements. I can't seem to pad the data to the required number of columns.

### Sample Data

```
table Students(id, name)
values
    (1, Alex),
    (2, Bob),
    (3, Charlie),
    (4, David)

table Hobbies (studentId, hobby)
values
    (2,'skating')
    (2,'sailing')
    (3,'reading')
    (4,'video games')
    (4,'paintball')
    (4,'nascar')
    (4,'baseball')
```

### Desired Output

```
[ID][OutputString]
[0][Student,Hobby1,Hobby2,Hobby3,Hobby4]
[1][Alex,,,,]
[2][Bob,skating,sailing,]
[3][Charlie,reading,,,]
[4][David,video games,paintball,nascar,baseball]
```

### Broken PseudoCode

```
DECLARE @maxHobbies INT = 4;
DECLARE @hobbyCount INT = 1;

DECLARE headerString varchar(max) = 'Student';
WHILE @hobbyCount <= @maxHobbies
BEGIN
    set @headerString = @headerString + ',Hobby' + @hobbyCount
    @hobbyCount = @hobbyCount + 1
END

DECLARE @outputString varchar(max)
SET @outputString = concat(@headerSting, char(13)) +
SELECT 0 AS ID, @headerString AS OutputString
UNION 
SELECT
    id,
    name + (WHILE @hobbyCount <= @maxHobbies BEGIN
        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS SELECT hobby FROM Hobbies where studentId = Students.id
            THEN ',' + SELECT hobby FROM Hobbies where studentId = Students.id
            ELSE ','
        END)
    END)
FROM Students
```

Answer (score 1):

You want up to 4 hobbies.  You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select s.id,
       (s.name + ',' +
        max(case when seqnum = 1 then h.hobby else '' end) + ',' +
        max(case when seqnum = 2 then h.hobby else '' end) + ',' +
        max(case when seqnum = 3 then h.hobby else '' end) + ',' +
        max(case when seqnum = 4 then h.hobby else '' end)
       ) as outputstring
from students s left join
     (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by h.studentid order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from hobbies h
     ) h
     on h.studentid = s.id
group by s.id, s.name;
```

Comment: This is a good solution. But could it be made extensible to a variable max number of subcategories, potentially up to 100 without a hard limit on the max range?

Comment: @OfficeDev . . . Subcategories of what?  There is no such column in the table.